# What is the purpose of "Input Methods" in right click menu in console section of Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I right clicked on the console area in Eclipse and I was intending to select "Remove All Terminated", but accidentally I selected one of the options in "Input Methods" list. What are input methods anyway? And what was the default settings before I changed it?

I am using the following Eclipse version:

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)
Build id: 20140612-0600

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Should be different input method for different language, since I see IBus which is a common framework for different language, for example, Chinese. I guess when you need to interact with your program, that's place you go.